# Scraping Website that Requires QR code authentication

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape information from a website that requires me to use an app on my phone to authenticate a connection through a QR code to access the information I need. I've been thinking about 2 ways to proceed with this:

1. Selenium: Somehow implement a way to wait for user input (QR athentication) before scraping
2. Beautifulsoup: Somehow make a request to an already openend and authenticated website and scrape inforomation from there (rather than creating a new request this uses an already open "tab")

I've tried and been thinking how to do this and was hoping someone had experience on this or other insights on how to accomplish this.

Comment: What kind of scrapping do you need. If it is one/several-page scraping, you can just login manually and download an HTML of the page(s) and parse it with Beautifulsoup. 
Unfortunately, if there is no API for the service you are trying to scrap, I don't see how to do that automatically.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?